# How do I enable the root account in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, root

I know how to enable root account on Mac OS X Leopard, but not Snow Leopard or newer OS X versions. How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to enable it?  There's nothing I do that I can't just as conveniently do with sudo.

Comment: Sometimes even Apple tells you to enable the root user for some administrative tasks that are just easier using root: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1428

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The steps are covered in the article [Enable root account in Snow Leopard](http://snowleopardtips.net/tips/enable-root-account-in-snow-leopard.html) and this [Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528). Directory Utility is accessible through System Preferences on all versions of OS X since 10.6.

1. Go to *System Preferences » Users & Groups*, then click the padlock. Enter your password.
2. Click *Login Options*, then *Join…* in the right pane
3. In the new window, click *Open Directory Utility…*
4. From the *Edit* menu, select *Enable Root User*.
5. Select *Change Root Password* from the Edit menu and type in the new root password.
6. Click the padlock icon to lock the application again.

Answer (score 12):

If you need a full root shell and find sudoing cumbersome, you can do:

```
sudo su -
```

That will give you a normal UID 0 shell to play with.

Comment: 'sudo -i' does the same thing afaik.

Comment: I do it this way on the linux boxes I use too. There is no reason to have a root account anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Run in Terminal.app:

```
dsenableroot
```

source: http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/another-way-to-enable-and-disable-root.html

Answer (score 1):

Reference this link, do as follows:

[How to Enable the Root User Account in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/09/enable-root-user-account-os-x-lion/)

Terminal user can make it like this:

```
dsenableroot    #enable
dsenableroot -d #disable
```

Comment: Wow! I wish I know this years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo passwd` then `su -` will work with the new password.