# How to get real root permissions on OS X

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo

I'm a noob with OSX (10.8.5) wanting to install homebrew on an Airbook.

Installing homebrew fails straight away because it can't mkdir /usr/local.
So I try with sudo - same problem.
Trying
    sudo mkdir /usr/local
directly also fails of course.

My user 'mjb' has admin rights (well according to the Users/Groups GUI interface) but I can't figure out how to do anything useful !

As my 'admin' user mjb, typing id shows "uid=502(mjb) gid=20(staff) ...."
                   typing sudo id shows "uid=503(root) gid=1000 ...."

I've searched and all the solutions I see involve editing some file (root.plist) directly or using visudo ... and of course I don't have the permissions to do that !

I just want "real" sudo access so I can install stuff on the command-line (boot2docker).

Thanks for any suggestions

Update:

dscl . ls /Users provides a lot of output:

```
_amavisd
_appleevents
_appowner
_appserver
_ard
_assetcache
_atsserver
_avbdeviced
_calendar
_ces
_clamav
_coreaudiod
_cvmsroot
_cvs
_cyrus
_devdocs
_devicemgr
_dovecot
_dovenull
_dpaudio
_eppc
_ftp
_geod
_installassistant
_installer
_jabber
_kadmin_admin
_kadmin_changepw
_krb_anonymous
_krb_changepw
_krb_kadmin
_krb_kerberos
_krb_krbtgt
_krbtgt
_lda
_locationd
_lp
_mailman
_mcxalr
_mdnsresponder
_mysql
_netbios
_netstatistics
_networkd
_postfix
_postgres
_qtss
_sandbox
_screensaver
_scsd
_securityagent
_serialnumberd
_softwareupdate
_spotlight
_sshd
_svn
_taskgated
_teamsserver
_timezone
_tokend
_trustevaluationagent
_unknown
_update_sharing
_usbmuxd
_uucp
_warmd
_webauthserver
_windowserver
_www
daemon
mjb
nobody
Paulina
root
```

dscl . read /Users/root

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
NFSHomeDirectory: /Local/Users/root
Password: *
PasswordPolicyOptions: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">; 
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>failedLoginCount</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>failedLoginTimestamp</key>
    <date>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>lastLoginTimestamp</key>
    <date>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
    <key>passwordLastSetTime</key> 
    <date>2015-06-09T18:48:49Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>
PrimaryGroupID: 1000
RealName:
 Mike Bright
RecordName:
 root
 BUILTIN\Local System
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users 
SMBSID: S-1-5-18 
UniqueID: 503 
UserShell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: [Enabling and using the "root" user in OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) this [bing search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=root%20os%20x&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=root%20os%20x&sc=5-9&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=f7f56393a347488bbf01df451abc38d0) might also be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable the root account in Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/44603/how-do-i-enable-the-root-account-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: @Ramhound Not a dup. The fact that he can't do root-like things just by sudo'ing from an admin account makes it clear that something else is screwed up. The fact that the "root" account apparently shows as UID 503 instead of 0 is even more evidence.

Comment: What sort of error message do you recieve (if any) when you try `sudo mkdir /usr/local`?

Comment: sudo mkdir /usr/local
Password:
mkdir: /usr/local: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

The real superuser root account is always Always ALWAYS UID 0. How you got an account named "root" on your system with UID 503 is beyond me.

You may need to manually fix up your Directory Services data store (your users and groups database) with Directory Utility or `dscl`.

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/Directory\ Utility.app
```

I think that was the path back in 10.8.5, but it's been a long time. Nowadays it's…

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory\ Utility.app
```

That app has a Directory Editor you should be able to use to see what's going on with the inner details of the accounts on your machine.

Alternatively, seeing the output of the following two commands would help me see what's going on:

```
dscl . ls /Users
dscl . read /Users/root
```

Comment: Thanks.for your suggestions.  Running that first Open command (that is the correct path) gives me the error (whether I use sudo or not):   LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /System/Library/CoreServices/Directory Utility.app.

Comment: dscl . ls /Users provides a lot of output:    _amavisd
_appleevents
_appowner
_appserver
_ard
_assetcache
_atsserver
_avbdeviced
_calendar
_ces
_clamav
_coreaudiod
_cvmsroot
_cvs
_cyrus
_devdocs
_devicemgr
_dovecot
_dovenull
_dpaudio
_eppc
_ftp
_geod
_installassistant
_installer
_jabber
_kadmin_admin
_kadmin_changepw
_krb_anonymous
_krb_changepw
_krb_kadmin
_krb_kerberos
_krb_krbtgt
_krbtgt
_lda
_locationd
_lp
_mailman
_mcxalr
_mdnsresponder
_mysql
_netbios
_netstatistics
_networkd
_postfix
_postgres
_qtss
_sandbox
_screensaver

Comment: dscl . ls /Users output continued .... _scsd
_securityagent
_serialnumberd
_softwareupdate
_spotlight
_sshd
_svn
_taskgated
_teamsserver
_timezone
_tokend
_trustevaluationagent
_unknown
_update_sharing
_usbmuxd
_uucp
_warmd
_webauthserver
_windowserver
_www
daemon
mjb
nobody
Paulina
root

Comment: $ dscl . read /Users/root
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
NFSHomeDirectory: /Local/Users/root
Password: *
PasswordPolicyOptions:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

Comment: <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>failedLoginCount</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>failedLoginTimestamp</key>
        <date>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
        <key>lastLoginTimestamp</key>
        <date>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</date>
        <key>passwordLastSetTime</key>
        <date>2015-06-09T18:48:49Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>

PrimaryGroupID: 1000
RealName:
 Mike Bright
RecordName:
 root
 BUILTIN\Local System
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
SMBSID: S-1-5-18
UniqueID: 503
UserShell: /bin/bash

Comment: @mjbright Yeeahh… that's a messed up user database alright. I have no idea how it got that way, and I'm not sure if trying to hand-edit it back into working order is likely to work. Especially since you don't seem to be able to do anything with super user privs right now. I'd recommend doing a full Time Machine backup (or other full backup), **test your backup**, then format your drive and do a clean re-install of the OS, and then use Migration Assistant to migrate just your mjb and Paulina accounts.

Comment: Ouch !  Thanks a lot for your comments.  Strange that it should be in this state ... it's only been "used by a little old (young) lady to go to church (univ.) once a week" .... ok, I'll do a reinstall at some point ...

Comment: Just to close on this, I reinstalled (actually upgraded to Yosemite at the same time) and sudo is working fine now.    As I said I'm a noob with OSX so it was particularly pleasing to see that I could reinstall/upgrade the OS without having to recreate my users (I was assuming I'd have to do a more radical reinstall because of this "user database" problem ... but it wasn't necessary).  Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: @mjbright Thanks for the follow up. Does root show up as uid 0 now?

Comment: Yes, sudo id now gives "uid=0(root) ..." and I have homebrew and stuff installed now which was the goal ... to get vbox/vagrant/docker/...